# Any way to tell when any button in a layout is UN-pressed

Tags: android

(Android 3.2) I have a TableLayout with 9 buttons.   I want to know when any of them are un-pressed, i.e., when a press is complete, i.e., ACTION_UP.     I don't care which button, I just want to know when any button which had been pressed has just been released.

I was hoping there was an **Android::onTouch** in the XML, like there is an Android::onClick, and I could point them all at one onTouch event handler to look for an ACTION_UP.   But there isn't.    I'm trying to avoid writing 9 separate OnTouchListeners.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you add onTouchListener from code and indeed, do what you want to do when you have ACTION_UP, as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: you will have only one touch listener in your class and add listener for all your 9 buttons

Comment: Everybody had the right idea- one listener - but gabi had it first so I marked that the right answer and +1'ed everybody.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

why not just create a single listener:

```
OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Button b = (Button) v; // the button that just gets released
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

and attach to all the buttons using a loop:

```
Button buttons[] = {...};
for (Button b : buttons) {
    b.setOnTouchListener(listener);
}
```

or alternatively:

```
int button_ids[] = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, ...};
for (int id : button_ids) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setOnTouchListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign each view to a single onTouch listener programmatically instead of in the XML.

Make one listener:

```
private View.OnTouchListener myListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // Your logic            
        return false;
    }
};
```

and then add that to each button.

```
findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnTouchListner(myListener);
findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnTouchListner(myListener);
```

Optimally you could create these buttons programmatically instead of referencing them from xml so you can do this in loops, or possibly put them in one ViewGroup and iterate though its children and add the listeners that way.